# How to add controllers to a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive in my app. However, I need to use directive in different places and they have their own controller.

so in my directive

```
directive('test', [function($popover) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            }
        };
    }
])
```

How do I add two controllers to one directive?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can not inject two controllers , you should think about another approach

Comment: You do not have to inject controller. You can use the controller specified as attribute. Is that kind of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `name` and `controller="@"` option.

```
.directive('test', [function($popover) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            controller : "@", 
            name:"controller",
            template:'<div>{{value}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            }
        };
    }
```

Ex:-

```
  <test controller="ctrl1"></test>
   .....
  <test controller="ctrl2"></test>
```

When you specify `controller= '@'` angular will look for the registered controller with the attribute value specified for the element's attribute (You can give any name for the attribute) mentioned in the `name` option.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CynkzY?p=preview)**

Here is the snippet from angular directive implementation:-

```
         if (controllerDirectives) {
         ....

            controller = directive.controller;
            if (controller == '@') {
              controller = attrs[directive.name];
            }

            controllerInstance = $controller(controller, locals);
```

Comment: Hmmm...  Can't find that in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  How did you find this out?  It's kind of confusing, what about using the same "@" as you use to bind in isolated scope binding, and the apparently undocumented `name` property is used to specify the controller attribute name, so you could have `name:"ctrl",` and it would use the `crtl` attribute instead of `controller`, but you still need `controller: "@",`...

Comment: I had found it long time back while looking at the angular directive implementation, then i tried out but this is not documented i don't know why. You could use any name for the attribute where you can specify the controller. it looks for `@` as the controller name. It has nothing to do with the isolate scope's `@`. They are 2 different implementation.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat See the updated answer with the section from the angular snippet.